# PHP Triggering Actions Based on Dates

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I am trying to make an area on my Wordpress site that checks the date field on each of my custom post type posts each time I get on for any dates that are 7 days or less until the current date and then displays the corresponding post title. If you have questions about any of that, please just ask, it is hard to really explain it.

I would like to put an if statement in there that just says if any of the dates are 7 days or closer to the current date, display the title of that post.

Problems:

The whole the_field( 'contract_sign_date' ); function displays the date as mm/dd/yy, so I'm not sure if subtracting the_field( 'contract_sign_date' ) by the current date will even come out right.

If problem 1 would for some reason work, what if the contract sign date is the first of the month? 1 - 7 will = -6 instead of the current date.

Like I said, if you have questions about any of that, please just ask, it is hard to really explain it.

Comment: If you have access to the database you can run a query like: 

SELECT someidfield, sometitlefield FROM sometable
WHERE somedatefield BETWEEN date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and now()

Comment: I have access to a database, but I am not very familiar with SQL at all. I am more along the lines of PHP HTML and CSS. Would you mind to message with me so that we can get off the comments? I have a few questions.

Comment: Or can you even do messages on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Not sure if you can do messages on here.  There might be a way to do what you're asking for without having to query the database yourself but I think a query would be the most logical way.  If you want to do this kind of dynamic stuff on your WordPress you should learn some basic MySQL!  It's not very tough.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go this may help you get what you may need from wordpress

```
$contract_date = date(the_field( 'contract_sign_date' ));
$contract_date = strtotime ('-7 days', strtotime($contract_date) ) ;
$args = array(
  'date_query' => array(
    array(
      'after' => array(
        'year'  => date ('Y', $contract_date),
        'month' => date('m', $contract_date),
        'day'   => date('d', $contract_date)
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```